# How to optimize retrieval of 10 most frequent words inside a json data object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, python-requests, word-frequency

I'm looking for ways to make the code more efficient (runtime and memory complexity)
Should I use something like a Max-Heap? 
Is the bad performance due to the string concatenation or sorting the dictionary not in-place or something else?
**Edit: I replaced the dictionary/map object to applying a Counter method on a list of all retrieved names (with duplicates)**

**minimal request:**  script should take less then 30 seconds
 **current runtime:** it takes 54 seconds

```
   # Try to implement the program efficiently (running the script should take less then 30 seconds)
import requests

# Requests is an elegant and simple HTTP library for Python, built for human beings.
# Requests is the only Non-GMO HTTP library for Python, safe for human consumption.
# Requests is not a built in module (does not come with the default python installation), so you will have to install it:
# http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.9.1/
# installing it for pyCharm is not so easy and takes a lot of troubleshooting (problems with pip's main version)
# use conda/pip install requests instead

import json

# dict subclass for counting hashable objects
from collections import Counter

#import heapq

import datetime

url = 'https://api.namefake.com'
# a "global" list object. TODO: try to make it "static" (local to the file)
words = []

#####################################################################################
# Calls the site http://www.namefake.com  100 times and retrieves random names
# Examples for the format of the names from this site:
# Dr. Willis Lang IV
# Lily Purdy Jr.
# Dameon Bogisich
# Ms. Zora Padberg V
# Luther Krajcik Sr.
# Prof. Helmer Schaden            etc....
#####################################################################################

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

t = datetime.datetime.now()

for x in range(100):
    # for each name, break it to first and last name
    # no need for authentication
    # http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.3.0/user/quickstart/#make-a-request
    responseObj = requests.get(url, verify=False)

    # Decoding JSON data from returned response object text
    # Deserialize ``s`` (a ``str``, ``bytes`` or ``bytearray`` instance
    #    containing a JSON document) to a Python object.
    jsonData = json.loads(responseObj.text)
    x = jsonData['name']

    newName = ""
    for full_name in x:
        # make a string from the decoded python object concatenation
        newName += str(full_name)

    # split by whitespaces
    y = newName.split()

    # parse the first name (check first if header exists (Prof. , Dr. , Mr. , Miss)
    if "." in y[0] or "Miss" in y[0]:
        words.append(y[2])
    else:
        words.append(y[0])

    words.append(y[1])

# Return the top 10 words that appear most frequently, together with the number of times, each word appeared.
# Output example: ['Weber', 'Kris', 'Wyman', 'Rice', 'Quigley', 'Goodwin', 'Lebsack', 'Feeney', 'West', 'Marlen']
# (We don't care whether the word was a first or a last name)

# list of tuples
top_ten =Counter(words).most_common(10)

top_names_list = [name[0] for name in top_ten ]

print((datetime.datetime.now()-t).total_seconds())

print(top_names_list)
```

Comment: use collections.Counter?

Comment: SO is for non-working code. Workiung code reviews _may_ be on topic on codereview.stackexchange.com - read and heed their FAQ before posting.

Comment: I tried by it didn't work / still ran slow

Comment: @PatrickArtner , I didn't know. thanks for informing me

Comment: For performance optimization use profiling - see where your code is slow - if calling an API 100 times takes 70s and the rest of your code is ok, look for other API-endpoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling an endpoint of an API that generates dummy information *one* person at a time - that takes considerable amount of time.

The rest of the code is taking almost no time.

Change the endpoint you are using (there is no bulk-name-gathering on the one you use) or use built-in dummy data provided by python modules.

---

You can clearly see that "counting and processing names" is not the bottleneck here:

```
from faker import Faker          # python module that generates dummy data
from collections import Counter
import datetime
fake = Faker()
c = Counter()

# get 10.000 names, split them and add 1st part
t = datetime.datetime.now() 
c.update( (fake.name().split()[0] for _ in range(10000)) )

print(c.most_common(10))
print((datetime.datetime.now()-t).total_seconds())
```

Output for 10000 names:

```
[('Michael', 222), ('David', 160), ('James', 140), ('Jennifer', 134), 
 ('Christopher', 125), ('Robert', 124), ('John', 120), ('William', 111), 
 ('Matthew', 111), ('Lisa', 101)]
```

in

```
1.886564 # seconds
```

---

General advise for code optimization: *measure first* then optimize the *bottlenecks*.

If you need a *codereview* you can check https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and see if your code fits with the requirements for the codereview stackexchange site. As with SO some effort should be put into the question first - i.e. analyzing *where* the majority of your time is being spent.

---

Edit - with performance measurements:

```
import requests
import json
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime


# defaultdict is (in this case) better then Counter because you add 1 name at a time
# Counter is superiour if you update whole iterables of names at a time 
d = defaultdict(int)

def insertToDict(n):
    d[n] += 1

url = 'https://api.namefake.com'
api_times = []
process_times = []
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
for x in range(10):
    # for each name, break it to first and last name
    try:
        t = datetime.datetime.now()      # start time for API call
        # no need for authentication
        responseObj = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        jsonData = json.loads(responseObj.text)

        # end time for API call
        api_times.append( (datetime.datetime.now()-t).total_seconds() )
        x = jsonData['name']

        t = datetime.datetime.now()      # start time for name processing
        newName = ""
        for name_char in x:
            # make a string from the decoded python object concatenation
            newName = newName + str(name_char)

        # split by whitespaces
        y = newName.split()

        # parse the first name (check first if header exists (Prof. , Dr. , Mr. , Miss)
        if "." in y[0] or "Miss" in y[0]:
            insertToDict(y[2])
        else:
            insertToDict(y[0])
        insertToDict(y[1])

        # end time for name processing
        process_times.append( (datetime.datetime.now()-t).total_seconds() )
    except:
        continue

newA = sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)[:10]
print(newA)
print(sum(api_times))
print(sum( process_times ))
```

Output:

```
['Ruecker', 'Clare', 'Darryl', 'Edgardo', 'Konopelski', 'Nettie', 'Price',
 'Isobel', 'Bashirian', 'Ben']
6.533625
0.000206
```

You can make the parsing part better .. I did not, because it does not matter.

---

It is better to use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for performance testing (it calls code multiple times and averages, smoothing artifacts due to caching/lag/...) (thx @[bruno desthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) ) - in this case I did not use timeit because I do not want to call API 100000 times to average results

Comment: well,I was requested to use the names from this website. and you say thats the problem?

Comment: Because it doesn't support bulk queries?

Comment: @generationX No. What I tell you is: you have to analyze where the bottlenecks are. See edit. When calling the API for 10 names it takes `6.5` seconds ...the (inefficient -to be optimized-) analysis and counting code for the API-Result takes `0.0002` seconds ...where do you think you can optimize?

Comment: @generationX you did see that I reduced the 100 calls to only 10 ... the main point here is that the API takes _most_ of the time, the processing is insignificant. You are unable to optimize the API return times... and optimizing the "parsing" does not reduce the codes runtime significantly

Comment: Yes, this was clear. So basically the guy who gave me this assignment is a j#rk? (which means I couldn't reach 30 seconds?)

Comment: @PatrickArtner for benchmarks, better to use the `timeit` module.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers fully agree - do you think it matters here?

Comment: @generationX That depends on your task. Create one program to call the API of the site, store 1000 results in a file. Perform your code using the data from the file. Try to make parallel requests to the site see if that speeds it up enough to get below 30s (I doubt it) , .... with your current code, you won't. Processing is **not** the bottleneck.

Comment: @PatrickArtner not necessarily indeed - but I thought it was worth mentionning nonetheless for readers that don't know about this module.

Comment: @PatrickArtner , wait a sec - Do you think the trick was to use Asynchronous(I/O?) calls? -aka non blocking requests ïn parallel? I have used Tornado in the past